# React Native Fecth blocks interations

Tags: reactjs, react-native

On android, when I'm fetching something, it blocks any interations on scene until fetch it's done. I'm currently using `InteractionManager`

Before using `InteractionManager`, I tried fetching directly, but it caused lags on transitions.

Any toughts?

```
var ProductRender = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      product: null,
      modalVisible: false,
      description: null,
      ready: false
    };
  },




  componentDidMount: function() {
      InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        fetch(ENDPOINT)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({product : responseJson.product, related:     responseJson.related});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        });
      },
      });

  },  


  render: function() {...
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend implementing redux and study redux thunk and async actions a bit.

If you're dead set on using your fetch inside a class, I recommend creating a separate async method for it.

Comment: React Native can't handle this by itself?